# Using High School Algebra to turn first equation into format of second equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

This question is really bothering me.  It is just for personal study, but I can't seem to turn this one equation into the other just using basic algebra(in the high school sense)(wolfram alpha clearly says the equations are equal but I'm struggling showing/turning the first one into the other).
$$\frac{(1+i)z+(3+i)}{(-1+i)z+(3-i)}\quad=\quad i\times\frac{2-i+z}{2+i-z}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply numerator and denominator with $\color{blue}{1+i}$ and simplify:

$$\begin{align}\frac{(1+i)z+(3+i)}{(-1+i)z+(3-i)}
& = \frac{3+z+i(z+1)}{3-z+i(z-1)}\color{blue}{\frac{1+i}{1+i}} \\[6pt]
& = \cdots \\[6pt]
& = \frac{2+2iz+4i}{4-2z+2i} \\[6pt]
& = i\frac{ (2 - i) + z}{(2+i)-z} 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward, grind way is to set $z:= x + iy$ and make calculations to bring the numerator and denominator in the form $a+ib$ and then multiply the denominator with $a-ib$. It should 99.9% lead you to the result you got sooner or later ($a=Re\{denominator\}$ and $b = Im\{denominator\})$.

Comment: I tried it just now, and I honestly am not getting near the desired form at all.